# Calling "sed" from exec.Command

Tags: go

I'm currently having trouble trying to run this code which is supposed to call the unix command `sed` to find and replace the string `hello` with `goodbye` in the file `./myfile.txt`

This works fine if you run it from the command line, but if I try the same thing from my Go code....

```
command := exec.Command("sed", "-e \"s/hello/goodbye/g\" ./myfile.txt")
result,err := command.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(string(result))
```

Bit I just keep on getting this output

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `"'
```

Is there some sort of quote escaping going on or something to cause it to interpret the string wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following works:

```
command := exec.Command("sed", "-e","s/hello/goodbye/g","myfile.txt")
```

Comment: Note: `exec.Command("cmd", "a1 a2", "a3")` is executed as `cmd "a1 a2" "a3"` - which is why it didn't work.

Comment: How can I add the string if it was a variable? e.g. instead of hard-coding "goodbye", if my string was `s := "goodbye"` , how to add?